# ms access how to use only one column in a combobox to set the value of a field in a table?

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables - 'Customers' and 'Items' which are connected by one to many relationship ('CustomerID' field (primary key) in 'Customers' table is related to many 'CustomerID's in 'Items').

I also have a form for Items table. In this form, i have a combobox with two columns -  names of the customer and the customerIDs (both from Customers table). When the user chooses an option i want to insert only the CustomerID in the 'Items' table.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This should happen automatically. Only the value in the **bound column** is used.

Comment: @Andre Sorry for my ignorance but what is bound column?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/boundcolumn-property-2524fb4c-20ef-4b4e-a5ed-f1e5952ec459 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360567/what-is-the-purpose-of-bound-column-property-of-listbox-in-ms-access

Comment: Good reference for this case  https://www.techonthenet.com/access/comboboxes/bind_index2007.php

Comment: @Andre thank you! that helped!

Comment: @Santosh thank you very much!